# Small clarification Spivak Chapter 1, 18(b)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Suppose that ${b}^{2} - 4c < 0$. Show that there are no numbers $x$ satisfying ${x}^{2} + bx + c = 0$; in fact, ${x}^{2} + bx + c > 0$ for all $x$. Hint; Complete the square.

There is one answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797145/spivak-calculus-chapter-1-question-18-b).

**Solution (per Spivak)**

> We have
> ${x}^{2} + bx + c = \left (x + \frac{b}{2} \right)^{2} + \left(c - \frac{b^{2}}{4} \right) \ge c - \frac{b^{2}}{4} $

**Analysis**
$\left (x + \frac{b}{2} \right)^{2} $ is  $\ge 0$ as any real number $a$, $a^{2} \ge 0$
$\left(c - \frac{b^{2}}{4} \right)$ See question below.

Spivak now states

> but $c - \frac{b^{2}}{4} > 0$, so ${x}^{2} + bx + c > 0$ for all $x$

**Question**

Ignoring the conclusion (included for completeness), what allows him to assert $c - \frac{b^{2}}{4} > 0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the assumption (given condition) was,
$$b^2-4c<0\implies c-\frac{b^2}{4}>0.$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I was making it too complicated.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: I think the second line of my ‘analysis’ is incorrect, and I should probably correct that to ‘$>0$ by negated assumption’

Comment: @user1115542 Yes, you are right.

Comment: I modified the question to still maintain the spirit of the question, accepting your reply as the accepted answer.

Comment: Sathvik... would you care to comment on the construct that Spivak uses ie having $c - \frac{b^{2}}{4}$ on either side of the inequality sign. Completing the square accounts for the $c - \frac{b^{2}}{4}$ to the left of the inequality. Thanks.

Comment: He is using the fact that the square of a real number is non-negative. Hence, $$(x+b/2)^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4}\ge 0+c-\frac{b^2}{4}$$

Comment: As I thought about it, I assumed by doing this, you actually isolate $\left (x + \frac{b}{2} \right)^{2}$. That would more directly meet the proof. And, as you answered in the question, we have proved $c - \frac{b^{2}}{4} > 0$ which "cancels" out on either side of the inequality. If that makes sense :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130856/discussion-between-user1115542-and-sathvik-acharya).